# Predicting concentration values based on age values

Tags: r, model, predict

So, I have developed a simple linear model between glucose concentration and age. I have 315 observations in my whole dataset.

But, I want my model to predict the concentration of glucose for those aged 42, 72, and 76 years of age.

I am writing the following codes,

```
Retinol.age= lm(TPretinol$retplasma~TPretinol$age, data=TPretinol)
new.age <- data.frame(age = c(40,72,76))
predicted.age = predict(Retinol.age, new.age)
```

but R is showing ALL of the predicted values for the 315 observations. How can I stop that??

I am getting this error:

> 'newdata' had 3 rows but variables found have 315 rows

What can I do in order to obtain the desired predictions?

Comment: In the call to `lm` remove the `TPretinol$` part. The `data` argument is meant for that.

Comment: Yes true. I removed it

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: It did not work, only after i worked on the names of the variables, they have to be used in the same way.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(TPretinol)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(TPretinol, 20))`.